# How to check a list of list present in list without order

Tags: python, list

```
all_combination = [[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']], [['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b']]]
```

assume that, `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']] = [['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b']]`
I want to remove the duplicate list from list but the order doesn't matter. and more thing i need a `if` condition that checks that both `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]` is equal to `[['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b']]`.

This is my code i have tried so far.

```
all_combination = [[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']], [['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b']]]

unique = []
new = []
status = False
for i in all_combination:
    for j in i:
        for k in range(len(all_combination)):
            l = k+1
            for m in range(l, len(i)):
                if j == all_combination[k][m]:
                    unique.append(i)
print(new)
```

**Expected Answer:**

```
[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']]]
```

or

```
[[['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']], [['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b']]]
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: `c = Counter([tuple(sorted(l)) for l in list1])
result = [list(k) for k,v in c.items() if v==1]`

Comment: kindly remove the down vote i have provided the my code

Comment: Now you have a nested list with 2 levels...? Please make sure that the question details are clear from the beginning to avoid have answerers wasting time

Comment: yes basically this is my actual problem

Comment: I thought i will do it with by knowing simple example

Comment: but unfortunately its not happen

Comment: I fail to see how the expected output in your second case is related to the rules you described in the first part.

Comment: yes yes i have updated the question it was my bad

Comment: kindly remove the down votes i have updated my question

Comment: really sorry guys for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
all_combination = [[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']], [['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b']]]

tmp = []
for data_list in all_combination:
    for data in data_list:
        if data not in tmp:
            tmp = tmp + [data]

print(tmp)
```

`result = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']]`

Comment: really sorry guys for the misunderstanding kindly please remove the down votes. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
list2 = [e for e in list1 if set(e) == {"a", "b"}]
```

Comparison between sets is independent of order.

Comment: The `set` part is right. But the answer is too specific. It should be generalised I guess.

Comment: I can't make it more general if the question doesn't describe any more general requirements.

Comment: The question seems to be about removing duplicates, where order doesn't matter. I can't see how this helps, since it only works for this list

Comment: guys kindly have a look on my below expected answer.

Comment: really sorry guys for the misunderstanding kindly please remove the down votes. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

use `set`

sets don't care about the order

but they also don't care about the count

```
list1 = [["a","b"], ["c","d"], ["b","a"]]
list1 = [set(i) for i in list1]
ret = [list(i) for i in list1 if list1.count(i) ==1 ]
print (ret)
```

Comment: guys kindly have a look on my below expected answer.

Comment: really sorry guys for the misunderstanding kindly please remove the down votes. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the duplicates you can do this (independent of order):

```
list1 = [["a","b"], ["c","d"], ["b","a"]]

uniques = set([frozenset(x) for x in list1])
uniques = [list(x) for x in uniques]
```

one line version

```
uniques = [list(x) for x in set([frozenset(x) for x in list1])]
```

Comment: guys kindly have a look on my below expected answer.

Comment: really sorry guys for the misunderstanding kindly please remove the down votes. Thank You.

Comment: Thank you so much @Fredrik Nilsson, Thanks for this act of kindness. :')

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

list1 = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["b", "a"]]

list1_counter = Counter([frozenset(sub_list1) for sub_list1 in list])
list2 = []

for sub_list1 in list1:
    if list1_counter[frozenset(sub_list1)] == 1:
        list2.append(sub_list1)
```

`list2` after this would equal `[["c", "d"]]`.

`list2` also preserves the order of the lists within `list1`.

Comment: guys kindly have a look on my below expected answer.

Comment: really sorry guys for the misunderstanding kindly please remove the down votes. Thank You.